# What are Jaedong's build orders in ZvP?

Tags: starcraft-zerg, starcraft

Jaedong is considered the best Zerg in the world, but I'm having trouble finding information about it and his replays are difficult to find.

What are his preferred build orders against Protoss, particularly from the last couple of years? If possible, I'd love to know the specifics, down to when he transfers drones, etc.

Comment: Please use [this meta-thread](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5519/people-dont-understand-what-should-i-do) to discuss this question.

Comment: Hey Xitcod13, are you satisfied with Decency's answer? I agree with him, Jaedong used 3 hatch spire into 5 hatch hydra almost every time he played a standard ZvP. If not, what else would you like to know?

Comment: @BBz I would like to know the in-dept build order. I know it varies from map to map but its much easier to copy someone when you know on which supply they do what. like is it 21 spire or is it 31 spire. I previously provided an example for what a build order should look like but it was edited out because I guess it was too lengthy

Answer (score 3):

[Here are some replays of Jaedong.](http://www.teamliquid.net/replay/index.php?player1=Jaedong&team1_race=Zerg&map=&description=&uploader=&player2=&team2_race=&search=1) Some are against non-Korean players, others are between top Korean professionals.

[Here](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=111169#7) is another replay pack. This one is a bit older, being from early 2010, but the differences since then will be extremely subtle (and probably far beyond the understanding of most players).

Suffice it to say that if Jaedong is using a build it's almost assuredly a versatile one and safe to replicate, but only if you can be (close to) as active as Jaedong. Expect to be microing and scouting furiously. This build: [Three base spire into 5 Hatch Hydra](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/3_Base_Spire_into_5_Hatch_Hydra_%28vs._Protoss%29) is probably the most common one you'll see in ZvP against FFE.

[Here](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft/Zerg_Strategy#Specific_Strategies) is a great list of Zerg builds for each matchup.

Comment: thanks I check them out too bad that there is only one recent pvz in the first list. Also I think the basic build for PvZ build order has actually changed since 2010 so there should be a difference (im not 100% sure of that)

Comment: PvZ hasn't changed significantly to my knowledge since Savior vs. Bisu in MSL 2007. There are of course slight innovations and adaptations, but nothing revolutionary. There are a variety of different acceptable builds.

Comment: Can you explain a little more about Jaedong's strategy in these? The original version of the question did mention looking for replays, but in the context of figuring out what Jaedong's build orders were.

Comment: @MarkTrapp "Lee Jae Dong in ZvP innovated with the 3 Hatch Spire into 5 Hatch with Scourge play and popularized the build which made it the standard for ZvP."

Comment: I'm not sure if the builds in question correlate with the above statement without having watched them, as there are too many viable builds to possibly enumerate without significant effort.

Comment: @Decency The question's asking for build orders, but you've provided links to replays and a comment about whether it's okay to use Jaedong's build, which doesn't really address what it's after. If you can explain a bit about or excerpt something from those links that directly addresses what the question wants, add that to your answer: otherwise, this is more of an extended comment than a direct answer.

Comment: @MarkTrapp True; I've now linked to some elicited build orders as well.

Comment: This still seems to be little more than a link answer.  Your addition of "Here is a great list of zerg builds" is exactly what we want fleshed out and explained.

Comment: @fbueckert Does your browser not support hyperlinks?

Comment: @Decency: We strongly prefer answers that can stand on their own. Links are good to supplement an answer, but you should aim to have an answer that is useful even if all the links break.

Comment: @hammar If the links break, feel free to edit or flag my answer. Alternatively, you're more than welcome to do the hours of research/plagiarism necessary to replicate the information in the links and submit your own answer.

Comment: @Decency I feel like this is a discussion we've had with you on several occasions, but you just refuse to accept it. It isn't plagiarism so long as you cite your source. Posting link only answers is harmful to the site, in the event the link goes dead.

Comment: @Fluttershy Using content someone else created to draw undeserved attention is pretty much the definition of plagiarism, regardless of whether the original source is cited. If you want to talk about what's harmful to the site, I'd much rather have a broken link than stolen material.

Comment: @Decency if you cite your sources, it isn't plagiarism.  Otherwise no one would be able to write an academic paper anywhere, and that isn't true. Same goes for this.

Comment: @AshleyNunn Plagiarism.com: "Plagiarism is... copying so many words or ideas from a source that it makes up the majority of your work, whether you give credit or not"